# Separating Destination tables and Source tables from a query

Tags: python, oracle

I do have lot of queries that need to separate insert into (destination) table names as well as from (Source) table names.

Do you have any idea or a python code to separate them? I do have really large oracle stored procedure list.

Doing it manually is really time consuming. If someone has any clue for this, would be highly appreciated.

I need to separate only the destination tables and source tables..
Below is a sample query to work on

```
Create or replace procedure sfa.dlm_upload

BEGIN
INSERT INTO SFL.DFV_ALERT_INT
SELECT A.PROFILE_ID, A.AGENT_NAME, B.CONTACTR SRC_MSD, 
C.PROFILE_ID, B.DSR_PROFILE_ID
FROM EDW_TRD.RETAILER_SO1_DATA A, SFL.SFL_AGENT_DTL B, 
SFL.SFL_AGENT_DTL_TEMP C
WHERE A.PROFILE_ID = B.PROFILE_ID
AND B.DSR_ID = C.AGENT_ID
AND C.AGENT_STATUS = 'Active'
AND MONTH_KEY = (SELECT MAX(MONTH_KEY) FROM 
EDW_TRD.RETAILER_SO1_DATAMART)

;

INSERT OVERWRITE INTO SFL.MLV_ALERT_INTER
SELECT PROFILE_ID, TRUNC(PROFILE_CREATED_DATE) DATE_, 
COUNT(DISTINCT CONTRACT_ID)
FROM
(SELECT PROFILE_ID,PROFILE_CREATED_DATE, CONTRACT_ID
FROM MDW.RTV_PRE_CHANE_SALES
WHERE TRUNC(PROFILE_DATE,'MM') >= 
ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MM'),-2)
UNION ALL
SELECT TO_NUMBER(PMS_ID), PROFILE_CREATED_DATE, CONTRACT_ID
FROM MDW.MTV_POST_CHAN_SALES
WHERE TRUNC(PROFILE_CREATED_DATE,'MM') >= 
ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MM'),-2))
GROUP BY PROFILE_ID, TRUNC(PROFILE_CREATED_DATE);

END; 


OUTPUT - 

Destination tables
SFL.DFV_ALERT_INT
SFL.MLV_ALERT_INTER

Source tables
EDW_TRD.RETAILER_SO1_DATA
SFL.SFL_AGENT_DTL
SFL.SFL_AGENT_DTL_TEMP
MDW.RTV_PRE_CHANE_SALES
MDW.MTV_POST_CHAN_SALES
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Separate? How? Where? Why?

Comment: I dont know how to separate. I need to take out insert(destination) tables and from(source) tables.  Need a python code or something .. thnks

Comment: @SnyderFox, add 3 sample queries to your question and what result you expect to get from each of queries.